# Convert date to Julian in SharePoint Column to show YYYYMonth (spelled out)DD - 2018June15

Tags: date, sharepoint, julian-date

I want to set a sharepoint 2016 column to calculate a date that will render, for example, 2018June15. What is the formula for that? I'm not an excel formula expert or SharePoint expert. I'm just looking for a formula.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please find the below 2 examples and the description.

23-Feb-2017

```
 =TEXT(WEEKDAY([Column1]), "dddd")
```

Calculates the day of the week for the date and returns the full name of the day (Monday)

2-Jan-2003

```
=TEXT(WEEKDAY([Column1]), "ddd")
```

Calculates the day of the week for the date and returns the abbreviated name of the day (Thu)

Comment: Thank you very much!  I will try it.

Comment: You are welcome. Please get back to here for any help

Comment: I ended up using the formula: =TEXT(TODAY(),"yyyy-mmm-d")
to get a date like:  23-Sept-2018